# Unable to iterate trough available Jenkins slaves and create parallel stages with results

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Currently, I'm trying to iterate through the results of the current online Jenkins Slaves in order to execute commands inside of each one, but currently, I'm not sure what I could be missing since creating parallel stages based on the available agents isn't working as expected.

This is the current code that I'm using:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance
                    def computers = jenkins.computers
                    agents = [:]
                    for (i in computers) {
                        // Printing the output works, 
                        echo "${i.displayName}"
                        if (i.hostName) {
                            // this doesn't works
                            agents["${i.displayName}"] = {
                                echo 'this would be executed'
                            }     
                            // end                  
                        }   
                    }
                    parallel agents
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your script are you telling it to run your second echo step within that agent ?

Comment: @ben5556 when executing parallel agents.

Comment: I meant in your pipeline shouldn't you explicitly mention like label 'agent-name' for your stage/ pipeline to run inside that agent ?

Comment: @ben5556 you can see that I have specified that any agent can be used